# Google Apps Script Spreadsheets.Values.update function writing only blank cells

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-sheets-api

I have a function that copies and alters a large amount of data, then overwrites a sheet with the results. My code works correctly when I use `range.setValues(data)`, but it is exceedingly slow and sometimes errors out for that reason. I have switched my code to instead use the `Values.update()` function, but I am encountering an odd problem.

When my code is:

`const result = Sheets.Spreadsheets.Values.update(valueRange, ss.getId(), "Sheet Name", {valueInputOption: 'RAW'});`

the values are copied, but there are issues with the data types (currencies being interpreted as dates, etc.). I know the solution is to change the `valueInputOption`. However, when I use the following code:

`const result = Sheets.Spreadsheets.Values.update(valueRange, ss.getId(), "Sheet Name", {valueInputOption: 'USER_ENTERED'});`

the function finishes executing without an error but sheet is filled with entirely blank cells. Any idea why this may be?

Thanks!

Comment: In order to correctly understand your current situation, can you provide the sample value of `valueRange` and your sample expected result using the sample value?

Comment: Sure thing. an example of valueRange.values is:
`[[award status, acceptance status, last name, first name], [Accepted, Accepted, X1, Y1], [Accepted, Waitlisted, X2, Y2]]` . My expected result is a sheet that has a first row of award status, acceptance status, last name, first name; a second row of Accepted, Accepted, X1, Y1; etc.

Comment: Thank you for replying. I have to apologize for my poor English skill. Unfortunately, I cannot understand the relationship between `but there are issues with the data types (currencies being interpreted as dates, etc.).` and `[[award status, acceptance status, last name, first name], [Accepted, Accepted, X1, Y1], [Accepted, Waitlisted, X2, Y2]]`. By the way, are all values in your sample values variables? First, I would like to correctly understand your question.

Comment: Hi Tanaike, I apologize for the confusion, as I didn't include the accurate data types in my example above. Some of my data is in the form of currencies, such as a column titles "Award Amount" with an example value of "$2,500.00" . Some of it is also in the form of checkboxes, which are overwritten by the strings "true" and "false" when I use the `valueInputOption: 'RAW'`.

Comment: Thank you for replying. I would like to support you. But, I have to apologize for my poor English skill, again. Unfortunately, from your reply, I cannot still understand your question. But I would like to try to understand it. When I could correctly understand it, I would like to think of a solution. I would be grateful if you can forgive my poor English skill.

Comment: No worries at all, I've actually just figured out the issue! Before the above code was executing, I had a line to clear the range, using `range.clearContent();`. After clearing the range, I update the sheet with the data. However, Google Apps Script was waiting to clear the range until *after* I had written the content, so the sheet was ending up blank. I have fixed this issue by adding a `SpreadsheetApp.flush();` call directly after `range.clearContent()`. It is now working as intended.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Reposting here so I can mark resolved: I've actually just figured out the issue! Before the above code was executing, I had a line to clear the range, using `range.clearContent();`. After clearing the range, I update the sheet with the data. However, Google Apps Script was waiting to clear the range until after I had written the content, so the sheet was ending up blank. I have fixed this issue by adding a `SpreadsheetApp.flush();` call directly after `range.clearContent()`. It is now working as intended.